# How can I use headphone via Type-C port instead of jack in Laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, usb, audio

I have Lenovo V330-15IKB laptop and its headphone jack on the right side that I do not like. On the other hand, there are 2 Type-C USB ports on the left side of the laptop and I would like to use one of these Type-C ports in order to connect my headphone. Is it possible? If so, does it make any sense it the headphone port is connected via a converter from jack to Type-C? There are some suggestions e.g. BIOS settings, installing a driver, etc. (I use Windows 10). Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the images related to my headphone, converter and Windows Audio settings (there is only one option in the settings).

[image: Headphones]

[image: Adaptor]

[image: Settings]

Comment: It sounds like you want to keep your current headphones which have a 3.5 mm jack plug, so a "usb c headphone dac" would work. Or do you also use a microphone on your headphones?

Comment: I have just a simple headphones with mic feature and I can use both of these 2 features via 3.5 mm jack input. But I want to use them via Type-C port using the converter jack that I am also using with my phone and this headphone. Any idea to use this?

Comment: In that case, your search would be for "usb c headphone dac with mic input", as long as there is one TRRS 3.5 mm jack plug on the headset, as opposed to two plugs.

Comment: But I think my little headphone is also perform this as I can use both headphone and mic. So, I am mostly referring to the Windows settings that let me use Type-C port for this purpose?

Comment: Could you add a photo of the plug on the headphones to clarify the situation, please?

Comment: Yes, I added to the question.

Comment: Are you saying that you have the white part in the photo? If so, have you tried using it?

Comment: I have black and white and white is working on my mobile phone. But now with my laptop's type c port.

Comment: Can you tell us the make and model number of the white adapter?

Comment: It is noname, bought from aliexpress :) I am not waiting such a kind of feature from it :)

Comment: It looks like you want something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Headphone-Adapter-Earphone-Compatible-Black/dp/B082WG5VTK). I haven't tried one of those, and this is not a product recommendation.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an *active* type-C headset or adaptor, one that has a built in DAC, then it should work just work.

Active headsets should appear as both a pair of stereo headphones and a microphone to your PC. They are effectively a USB sound card with built in speakers and microphone.

From there it is just a matter of switching your audio input and outputs to use the headset. You can do this using the controls in your applications as well as the sound settings available when you left or right click on the volume icon in your taskbar.

The reason I mention *active* headsets is that there are a few rare headsets that come with phones that can put out analogue audio on the USB-C connector, those headsets may be passive and not have a DAC built in. Recent Samsung phones should come with *active* headsets that should be good to use with a computer.

Passive adaptors have no electronics that a "normal" USB port will understand and will not work. If you have a passive adaptor then it will work on your phone (if the phone supports it, many newer phones will not) but not a computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed exğlanations. I have a look at the Windows Audio settings before asking the question, but there is not a related menu for this purpose. So, where should I have a look on my laptop?

Comment: If you left-click the speaker icon you will get a volume slider and the name of the current playback (output) device. You can click that name to select a different device. If you right click and select "Open sound settings" you can choose both the input and output devices. If no new device shows up with your adaptor then chances are you have a passive converter which is useless on anything but your phone.

Comment: I added photos and setting screenshot. In this scene I am afraid I have no chance to use type-c port as audio jack :( Any possibility making a BIOS update/setting or installing a software?

Comment: Like I said, if you have an ***active*** adaptor then it should work. There are passive adaptors (wire only) and then there are active converters. Buy an active one. I have used one that looks almost the same as your image and it *does* work but if you have only a passive one then it will not. I got one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07M5K6M44/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and while cheap it *does* work.

Comment: Yes, the adaptor is passive of course. Is there an active type? Any example pls?

Comment: Yes. As I said in my answer you need an ***ACTIVE*** one with a DAC built in to it. I gave a link to one in my last comment. There is no "of course" here, they are difficult to tell apart without knowing what you have to begin with and you gave no information on what you actually had.

Comment: @Mokubai Does that unit work with a microphone too? That listing is unclear on the matter.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That one does. For me it shows up as Speaker (UC02) and Microphone (UC02) and works with a standard mobile phone 4-ring TRRS jack headset. Tested plugged in to my USB-C laptop. There is a note in the header for that page: " This usb c to 3.5mm headphone jack cable can support many brand 3.5mm headphone to **call and control volume**. But it can't support Apple 3.5mm headphone to call and up/down volume, only use to listen music."